# PrimeFaces Datatable Uncheck all checkboxes on click of pagination link

Tags: checkbox, primefaces, pagination, datatables

All the selected checkboxes of the primefaces datatable has to be unselected when the user clicks the pagination link of the primefaces dataTable. How can I achieve this?

Comment: Can you explain more about 'Pagination link' ?

Comment: Data in the table is displayed as five rows per page, so the next set of dat a will be in the next page, Page 1, 2, 3 ,....If i select few rows in the page 1  and if i move to page 2 then back to page 1, the rows remains selected in page 1, but i want its to get unchecked once if the user moves ..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `<p:ajax>` tag inside your `<p:dataTable>` tag to reset the selection of rows.

Here is the code :

```
 <p:ajax event="page" listener="#{testBean.deselectAll}" 
         update="dataTableId" />
```

In the **update** attribute you need to give your `<p:dataTable>` id.

For Backing Bean You need to unset all the rows as below :

```
public class testBean {
   // your code...

   public void deselectAll() {
        setYourSelectionList(null);
      //  OR
        setYourSelectionArray(null);
   }
}
```